# are airflow tasks scheduled based on the container time or the system time?

Tags: docker, time, airflow

I am running airflow in a docker container on my local machine

- if I open a terminal and `date` it returns **Wed Nov 22 18:36:44 EST 2023**
- if I do docker exec and run `date` inside the container it returns **Wed 22 Nov 2023 11:36:44 PM UTC**

when we define time in a DAG, it is like:

```
with DAG("forex_data_pipeline", start_date=datetime(2024, 1 ,1), 
    schedule_interval="@daily", catchup=False) as dag:
.
.
.
```

is it based on the UTC time or the EST time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would strongly recommand you to read [Airflow Documentation about TimeZones](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timezone.html).

The [start_date](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator) you provide is very important.

> The start_date for the task, determines the execution_date for the first task instance.

> Note that Airflow simply looks at the latest execution_date and adds the schedule_interval to determine the next execution_date

In Python, when you use a `datetime` without explicitly setting its [datetime.tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) then the based time is UTC.

> The datetime module provides timezone, a simple concrete subclass of tzinfo which can represent timezones with fixed offset from UTC such as UTC itself or North American EST and EDT.